# How to deploy Django repository from Github to cpanel for automatic changes

Tags: python, django, github, django-models, cpanel

I want to deploy my django website from github to cpanel for automatic update,I have managed to clone the repository in cpanel,The issue is that how do I deal with static files? as I know the static files settings are different from local development to a live server since in cpanel we have to keep them on the folder public_html.So how do I deal with this.

Comment: Create [separate settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings) for that deployment and collect static.

Comment: what settings Klaus D

Answer (score 0):

To serve your static files:

Apply settings bellow in your settings.py:

```
 # Static asset configuration
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Use Cling to set our WSGI.py file so first install following packages using pip:

```
pip install dj-static
pip install static3
```

In your **WSGI.py**

```
import os from django.core.wsgi 
import get_wsgi_application from dj_static 
import Cling os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ََAPPNAME.settings') application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Do not forget to run `python manage.py collectstatic`

[Source](https://medium.com/@devengine/deploy-your-django-app-to-cpanel-host-using-github-repository-95670a2abaaa)

Comment: So by doing this I will not have to copy the static files in the folder public_html right?

Comment: No, just run the following command ``python manage.py collectstatic`` once is setup and the static files will be collected for you

Comment: am getting an error Apache doesn't have read permissions to that file. Please fix the relevant file permissions. from passenger_wsgi.py

Comment: I have done that but static files don't work thats why I asked how do we handle static files